# Return results for closest Date if given Date does not exist in database using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to return a set of results based on a given date and if that date does not exist then then I want to return the result from the closet past date to that.

I am trying to return the results from an ApiController. The method I am using is pretty slow and I'm sure it's not the best one.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetItemsForDate(DateDTO Date)
    {
        using (var context = new CafeteriaContext())
        {
            bool vreauTOT = Date.vreauTOT;
            var itemsList = new List<MenuItem>();

            var getDates = context.MenuItems.Where(d => d.Date == Date.Date || d.Date < Date.Date).Select(d => d.Date).ToList();
            var availableDate = getDates.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).First();

            if (vreauTOT)
            { 
                itemsList = context.MenuItems
               .Where(d => d.Date == availableDate)
               .Select(r => r)
               .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                itemsList = context.MenuItems
                    .Where(d => d.Date == availableDate)
                    .Where(d => d.OnlyExternal == false)
                    .Select(r => r)
                    .ToList();
            }

            return Ok(itemsList);
        }
```

Is it possible to save a trip to the database and maybe construct a single query that will return the same results ? Or maybe a faster way than what I am doing right now.

Comment: Do you want the closest date in the 1) past, the 2) future or the closest 3) no matter if it is in the past or future.

Comment: If the requested date is not available then I want the results for the  closest past date that exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
itemsList = context.MenuItems
               .Where(d => d.Date == availableDate)
               .Select(r => r)
               .ToList();
```

No need to use Select here.

```
 itemsList = context.MenuItems
                    .Where(d => d.Date == availableDate)
                    .Where(d => d.OnlyExternal == false)
                    .Select(r => r)
                    .ToList();
```

No need to use Select here.
Use 1 where and check the conditions there:

```
.Where(d => d.Date == availableDate && ! d.OnlyExternal)
```

Explanation: each LINQ-method will perform a loop in the background, and the more loops you create, the slower it will run.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @SorinVasiliu you're welcome. That's the way to learn and improve your skills!

Comment: I'll mark this one as solution because it improved the speed of code and came also with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need `if .. else` here. It can be reduced to below using compound condition

```
         itemsList = context.MenuItems
                .Where(d => d.Date == availableDate && (!vreauTOT && d => !d.OnlyExternal))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: How does this work: (!vreauTOT && d => !d.OnlyExternal).   In my case, if vreauTOT is true, I want all the results for the particular date. If vreauTOT is FALSE, then I want only the results where d.OnlyExternal is TRUE (d is a MenuItem object from the Database). @Rahul

Comment: I don't think I can remove the if...else or I did not understand your comment correctly.